interactive shell is showing on virtual box and not Ubuntu
I have been on this for hours now. I have figured out how to get the ubuntu.iso in the VM but whenever I load it, it shows the interactive shell. I used
fs0:
cd EFI
but ubuntu is not a directory on there just boot
but when ever I go to the boot directory it shows me three .efi files that I can't access.
Whenever I watch tutorials Ubuntu loads automatically when starting the VM
I've read forums from others with this issue and applied similar methods but it didn't work.
I tried ChatGPT and nothing.
I asked reddit for a similar problem and was able to get it resolved but now I am stuck on a new problem.
I updated my computer to mac os sequoia and i've also reinstalled the VM and Ubuntu.iso along with the extension pack.
I am at a lost if someone can assist me that would be great.
anyone willing to message me in private would be a plus cause then I can screenshot the problem

I solved the issue. I installed an ARM version

If you are installing a guest OS in a macOS environment running on an Apple computer that has an M series ARM-based processor, then the guest OS that you install in any VM application has to be compatible with ARM architecture too. The Ubuntu .iso that you download must be the ARM version in order for it to be compatible with the processor of an ARM-based host OS's computer.
